# excel seach and add value if not there

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking something similar to vlookup but with macro and with additional feature.I don't know where to begin need your help.

So I have a Sheet 1

```
Cell A1:  bu 200000 olacaktır
Cell A2:  BCD
Cell A3:  CDE
Cell A4:  DEF
```

Sheet2 :

```
A1: BCD
A2: DEF
```

So "bu 200000 olacaktır" and CDE is missing in Sheet 2 so I would like that these values added in Sheet2 cell a3 and sheet2 cell a4

Result should be similar to that
Sheet2 :

```
A1: BCD
A2: DEF
A3: bu 200000 olacaktır
A4: CDE
```

Any way to do this formula or macro ?

Hello all again, I did something with macro but got some small error, need your help to make it perfect.

```
Sub yenilikleri_ekle()

Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, lr As Long, rng As Range
Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input")
Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ayarlar")
lr = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = sh1.Range("B5:B" & lr)
For Each c In rng
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sh2.Range("A:A"), c.Value) = 0 Then
sh2.Range("A" & sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)(2) = c.Value
End If
Next
End Sub
```

It does the job but it confuses only if a cell containing some numbers in it for example

Did copied this bold value twice even it's already there,beside all others was ok.

**bu 200000 olacaktır**

So how can I improve the coding ?

Comment: I don't even know where to begin.I don't know any way to do it with function.I guess it should be with macro, right ?

Comment: The thing is, we don't know where to begin either, there are so many ways to do this with VBA. Maybe you ought to start with a VBA tutorial. It's really easy to pick up.

Comment: if you say there is no way with function, I will check what I can do with macro and put my progress here so that we can go over it.

Comment: Well, I don't know of any way to do it with functions. I'd be glad to help you with your VBA progression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't think this can easily be done with formulas.

The easiest way to proceed would be to :

1. Copy all the data from column A (in Sheet1)
2. Paste it at the end of column A (in Sheet2)
3. Select entire column A (in Sheet2)
4. Go in Data --> Data Tools --> Remove Duplicates
5. Click OK

---

Corrected your code to make it work properly. See the comments for the changes I made :

```
Sub yenilikleri_ekle()

    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, lr As Long, rng As Range

    Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input")
    Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ayarlar")

    lr = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row 'Changed column 1 for column 2, since you're after refering to column "B"

    Set rng = sh1.Range("B5:B" & lr)

    For Each c In rng
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sh2.Range("A:A"), c.Value) = 0 Then
            sh2.Range("A" & sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = c.Value 'Removed the (2) that had no meaning, and added a +1 to go to the next available line
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

---

Try replacing

```
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sh2.Range("A:A"), c.Value) = 0 Then
```

with

```
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sh2.Range("A:A"), CStr(c.Value)) = 0 Then
```

Comment: Bernard,I have done some macro working %90 effective got small problem can you help me with that ? I edited my answer containing the macro code.

Comment: Yes Bernard,With the fix now it's working very well.Thank you very much

Comment: Superb! Glad I could help :D

Comment: Bernard, I came with an error Unable to get CountIF property of Worksheet class. I only came with this error when the cell value is long text. How can I fix it ?